# Intertial finite-size effects in fluid simulations

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, molecular-dynamics

A gradient $\nabla \rho$ in the density field $\rho$ of fluids at thermodynamic equilibrium is suppressed at a rate given by $D \nabla^{2} \rho$, allowing to measure the diffusivity $D$ of the fluid from the linear map between the density gradient and the rate of gradient suppression $\partial_{t}\rho\sim \nabla^{2} \rho$.

If the field $\rho$ shows ***net shifts*** or ***non-zero fluxes*** during the experiment, for example due to momentum exchange with rigid walls containing the fluid, then the measured fluctuations magnitude at equilibrium will be superimposed with a ***drift*** or an ***additional flux*** of the density field $\rho$. For this reason it is a standard that experimental authors include a correction to calculate the true fluctuations magnitude at equilibrium. (I would add references upon request)

The removal of net fluxes allows to calculate the ***fluctuations magnitude for stationary fluids***. In principle, this allows to compare with theories and computational particle based simulations, as these are typically done in stationary conditions. But here is my problem ; If we take molecular dynamics simulation of a thermal fluid in periodic boundary conditions, then the center of mass would be strictly equal to zero, and this should be consistent. But if we take a molecular dynamics simulations of a fluid confined between two walls, the fluid would be exchanging momentum with the walls. On average the center of mass of the fluid would be also equal to zero, ***but it would fluctuate***. These fluctuations go to zero as the particle number increases, but for finite particle numbers this means that the data are ***not truly in the reference of frame where the center of mass is resting***, which is what is obtained from experimental systems.

So for molecular dynamics simulations of fluid bounded by walls I expect that the fluctuations of the center of mass of the fluid give rise to finite-size effects. However I could not find discussions in the literature about such ***inertial finite-size effects*** and any hints would be appreciated.